# Pass Variable to Model

Tags: javascript, json, web2py

I am trying to pass a variable to a model function 'GetFiles' in web2py using the following code where the result is stored as 'a':

```
<script>
VARIABLE = 'teststring'
a = {{=XML(response.json(GetFiles(VARIABLE)))}}
</script>
```

When I run the page, VARIABLE is evaluated as a string literal instead of as 'teststring'.

The error message is:
NameError: name 'VARIABLE' is not defined

if I manually replace VARIABLE with its value, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
{{=XML(response.json(GetFiles(VARIABLE)))}}
```

is Python code that gets evaluated on the server before the HTML page is delivered to the browser. Therefore, it only recognizes variables that have been defined in the Python environment. On the other hand, the following code:

```
VARIABLE = 'teststring'
```

is Javascript, and doesn't get evaluated until the HTML page has been delivered to the browser (i.e., *after* the Python code has run).

If the value that gets passed to `GetFiles` is generated in the browser, then you cannot simply call the server-side Python function directly from the browser. Instead, you would have to make an Ajax call to the server.

Comment: I have this: ajax('{{=URL('Model', 'GetFiles')}}', ['data'], 'target') running inside my script tags now, but is there a way to assign the returned value to a variable instead of appending as innerHTML to 'target'?

Comment: The third argument to `ajax()` can be ":eval", in which case, you can return Javascript code that will get evaluated. The third argument can also be a Javascript function, which will be passed the return value.